# Check if R is installed from python

Tags: python, linux, r

I have a `python` code that calls many functions and one of those functions needs the [`R` software](http://cran.r-project.org/) installed to be able to run properly.

How can I check from within `python` if `R` is installed in the system so as to avoid calling that function if it is not?

BTW I'm running a Linux distro (elementary OS, based on Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dpkg -s` with subprocess:

```
from subprocess import check_output
print check_output(["dpkg", "-s" , "r-base"])
```

Or `which` as @kay suggests :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(["which", "R"],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
exit_code = proc.wait()
if exit_code == 0:
    print ("Installed")
```

Using `PIPE` you won't see `/usr/bin/R` in the output

Comment: Won't work for other distros (e.g. Fedora), or if the user has compiled and installed the program themselves.

Comment: @Kay, BTW I'm running a Linux distro (elementary OS, based on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: I read that part, but why give a specific answer if you can give a generic one?

Comment: @kay, because it is a specific question

Comment: OP said which OS he is using, not which OSes he is targetting. Sorry, I did not want to "belittle" your answer, only point out this portability issue.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm getting a `NameError: name 'Popen' is not defined` error. Any idea why?

Comment: Solved, I had to add `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE` and now it works. Great answer too!

Comment: @Gabriel sorry yes I forgot to add the imports!

Comment: I'm selecting this one since it gives a cleaner output (the second answer) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Simply test the outcome of `which R`:

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError

try:
     check_call(['which', 'R'])
except CalledProcessError:
     print 'Please install R!'
else:
     print 'R is installed!'
```

This will work on *BSD (including Mac OSX), too.

Comment: Kay, `R` should be in caps otherwise it doesn't work. Great answer!