# Check if Python is installed from R

Tags: python, r

What would be the most platform-independent way of checking whether Python is installed, from R? This question is actually the inverse of [Check if R is installed from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329955/check-if-r-is-installed-from-python).

EDIT:

Sys.which() does not, as far as I have experienced return the path of the Python executable, even though from the Windows command I can directly access python (meaning that the dir of the python executable is added to %PATH% variables?).

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481980/get-the-list-of-installed-packages-by-user-in-r)

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 that is to check for R packages, not external software such as Python.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, its my bad...

Comment: how about calling `python` from `R` and catching the error?

Comment: Not an `R` expert, but there must be a way to call a command. You could try running `python -v` and then parse the output. Even let's you check if it has the correct version you need

Comment: Under what circumstances does `Sys.which` not work?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck see edit. It never did in my particular case.

Comment: This would be a bug in `Sys.which` if true but somehow I suspect you are overlooking something.  Did you add it to the path after you started R?  Did you start R from the `cmd` line and add python to the path from a `cmd` process that had been started before you added python to the path?  If you are able to find an instance where `Sys.which` does not work yet python is on your path then reboot your machine and see if it is still the case.  Also try `shell("where python")` from the R console.

Comment: try `system2('python','-v', stdout = 'stdout.txt', stderr = 'stderr.txt')` then check the file or just `system2('python')`

Answer (score 0):

You can run this:

```
vv <- system("pyv=\"$(python -V)\" | echo $pyv| grep \"Python\"")
if(vv){
 print("Python is installed")
}
```

You could also use this if you were trying to determine which version of Python was on a computer:

```
vv <- system("pyv=\"$(python -V 2>&1)\" | echo $pyv | grep \"2.7\"")
if(vv){
 print("Python 2 is installed")
}

# or 
vv <- system("pyv=\"$(python -V 2>&1)\" | echo $pyv | grep \"3\"")
if(vv){
 print("Python 3 is installed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A great solution I was [just made aware](https://github.com/ropensci/software-review/issues/546#issuecomment-1416728843) of: combine `Sys.which` with `nzchar`.

If python cannot be found, `Sys.which` returns an emtpy character

```
Sys.which("python")
# ""
```

If python is found,

```
Sys.which("python")                                                                     # python 
# "C:\\...\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe"                                                                    python
```

```
nzchar("")
# FALSE
nzchar("A")
# TRUE
```